# Excessive heat from laptop when running Tails (Linux), but not Windows

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, overheating, tails

I recently got a laptop with a 4 core (8 thread) Intel i7 CPU, running Windows. Unless I'm really pushing it, it doesn't heat up very much. However when I installed Linux it began to heat up significantly and battery life got much shorter.  Specifically a this is a Debian-based live CD of [Tails](https://tails.boum.org) booted with `toram` so the disc is not inserted and the root filesystem is a `squashfs` image living in memory.

I'm aware that Windows has some power optimizations for power usage that Linux doesn't use by default, but here's where it gets weird:

- I disabled the discrete graphics chip by booting with `nouveau.modeset=0`.
- I disabled SMP, so the system is running only a single physical core.
- I used `cpufreq-set` to reduce the maximum clock rate to 800 MHz.

Despite all this, the laptop is getting *really* hot. If I leave it idling for an hour (CPU usage typically around 1% the entire time), it gets so hot that my kernel log starts accumulating overheating errors, saying that the CPU clock had to be throttled (it's already at its minimum and can't go any lower).

What in the world could be causing so much heat when I run Linux? How could a Windows system with 4 cores running at an average of 1.5 to 3 GHz at any given time and running the discrete GPU generate *significantly* less heat than a Linux system with a single enabled core running at 0.8 GHz?

The current output of `sensors` shows that the CPU itself isn't *that* hot:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +65.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        2880 RPM
```

The fan is under the control of the laptop's EC.

Comment: “Specifically a Debian-based live CD…” So did you actually install a real Linux install off of this CD? Or did you simply clone a live CD to the machine?

Comment: @JakeGould It's Tails, a live Debian system. It was booted with `toram` so the disc is not inserted. The root filesystem is a squashfs image living in memory.

Comment: This seems like it might be a very specific issue with Tails. Have you [seen this](https://www.reddit.com/r/tails/comments/9p4q8k/tails_freezing_after_approx_30_mins/)?

Comment: @JakeGould I strongly doubt it. Tails is barely changed from regular Debian Live. Anyway, if it was, it would most likely be the result of some program getting stuck in a loop and eating up the CPU. That means it's a kernel issue, and Tails does not use a custom kernel. I'm confident that it's not Tails-specific.

Comment: Maybe it is a Tails specific issue in the sense that it doesn't benefit from tweaks and specific firmwares that other distros that are meant to be installed and have repositories, etc.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I verified that it was not by stalling the boot in the initramfs shell instead of letting it continue booting and applying Tails-specific tweaks (modules, sysctls, etc.). Whatever it is equally applies to Debian Live. Not to mention, I can't think of any tweaks that Tails does which would cause this (I'm an on-and-off again Tails developer so have some familiarity with the codebase).